# What can I say about the dimension of all real functions?

Tags: vector-spaces

If I have a vector space of all real functions

And $S$ is all real functions with no constant term.

then $S$ is the subspace of $V$.

Then, What can I say about the dimension of $S$?

$V$ has infinite number of basis and $S$ seems to have infinite number of basis but it has one less basis because $S$ is all real functions with no constant term.

But, infinite $- 1$ is just infinite.

If both space have infinite basis,

Can I say $\dim S=\dim V$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'no constant term'?

Comment: In some way yes. The subspaces of an infinite dimensional vector space may have dimension equivalent to that of the original space. They are somewhat nestled.

Comment: I mean If you define g(x)=(x)derivative of f then g(x) has no constant term, isn't it right?

Comment: @aaa *All* the real functions includes nondifferentiable functions.

Comment: I think you are thinking of all real polynomials as $V$, not all real functions, from the "no constant term".  Both are infinite dimensional vector spaces.  As in other parts of math when you pass from the finite (dimension) to the infinite things do not behave as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If "with no constant term" is interpreted as $f(0)=0$, then both spaces have the same (infinite) dimension. In fact, as the whole space is simply $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ the dimension is...